# What is the field-distribution of users in this site? What % are biologists, chemists, and physicists?

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering. Are there any earth/atmospheric scientists here? What about astrophysicists?

Comment: We should have a poll or something. Is there any option to do this within meta.* or do we need to use an external site?

Comment: Following the example on [meta.tex.stackexchange](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls) each answer could be a field and the votes serve as the poll. The question is, how fine grain do we want to do it?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt is right.

Comment: Note, @Dr_bitz suggested a poll first, which reminded me of the one on meta.tex.

Comment: I'd like to suggest my field as Physics - Quantum Optics, along very rough boundaries in the research literature.

Comment: Are you allowed to upvote multiple options?  We're all interdisciplinary nowadays...

Comment: Sure, why not? 565 characters left.

Comment: @Mark then upvote [my physics answer](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21/89) and leave "Quantum Optics" as a comment (inlcude a wikipedia link if the character minimum is too low)

Comment: I think I may start a new community wiki question for this, in the interests of doing it right. Objections?

Comment: I've worked on projects in computational statistics, bioinformatics, computational biology, and applied probability, with some overlap between these areas. Most of these have involved some computation. I don't see any of this represented, but on the other hand, I'm not sure to put as an answer. Statistics, perhaps?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: you can just flag it for conversion to CW by the mods, but there's not much point. The justification for making poll questions CW is so that the posters of the popular answers don't accumulate rep for them, but there's no rep on meta anyway. Besides, the SE engine is not really for polls. Although I can see this question being of some use in early beta as we define the scope of the site, I don't think it's something that should stick around and become a continuous feature of the meta site. Once we go public, within a short time we'll have a pretty good idea of the distribution.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Agreed. This turned into a bit of a mess!

Comment: I propose we keep this only up until the end of the first week of public beta.

Comment: @J.M. I agree. I still encourage people to take a look at the poll on meta.tex that I referred to in the first comment. There was a bit more structure to that.

Answer (score 9):

I'm a Physicist. Go ahead and upvote this answer if you are one, upvote/post an answer of your own field if not.

Comment: [Nanophotonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanophotonics)

Comment: [Quantum Optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_optics)

Comment: [AMO Physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic,_molecular,_and_optical_physics)

Comment: Not as much now, but CFD; quantum turbulence, a bit meteo models.

Comment: I am also in AMO Physics.

Comment: My field is biophysics.

Comment: Experimental particle physics---and I somehow ended up being a Monte Carlo guy.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a computational scientist.

Answer (score 6):

I am an applied mathematician.

Comment: Specifically, I work in numerical analysis and hyperbolic PDEs

Comment: I work in numerical analysis including time-parallel algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a computational chemist, studying *ab initio* electronic structure methods, Molecular Dynamics,... etc.

Comment: I'm a chemist, but I take up mathematics as a serious hobby. :) I deal with numerics and special functions, among other things. I write programs from time to time.

Comment: @J.M. Cool... you might want to upvote the "question" if you consider yourself a computational chemist..

Comment: I haven't actually dealt with things like DFT and HF methods in full, so I can't consider myself a proper computational chemist.

Comment: Interesting, I'm a physicist doing the same thing.

Comment: I do MD, but am by training a chemical engineer. Quantum mech and Stat mech happens to be two of those highly cross-disciplinary fields that requires the willingness to go bonkers playing with mathematics.

Comment: @rcollyer: That's because *ab inito* QM is physics, but electronic structure of things more complicated than single atoms has traditionally been chemistry, no?

Comment: @dmckee I think its a mixed bag with the number of condensed matter and materials physics groups in physics departments.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in Aerospace Engineering studying CFD with combustion. Crossroads of fluid mechanics, thermodynamics (I use real gas equation of states), chemistry, programming and of course computational science.

Answer (score 2):

I work on problems related to genetics and genomics.

Answer (score 1):

I study aeronomy and atmospheric sciences.

Answer (score 1):

In my department of my current employer, the majority of folks are mechanical and civil engineers (I'm an electrical engineer). There are a number of other departments that work on pure and applied sciences.

There are many other disciplines practised [here](http://www.nrel.gov/science_technology/).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what hat I'm wearing and who you ask, I'm either a mathematical epidemiologist or biologist.

Answer (score 1):

I am a physical oceanographer and atmospheric scientist.

Have a B.Sc. in Meteorology, mostly computation and modeling oriented. Currently a third-year Ph.D. student in Physical Oceanography. Work focus is on how to conserve momentum and energy in a coupler atmosphere-wave-ocean modeling system.

Answer (score 0):

I am a computer scientist.

(this line added for required length)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Geophysicist.

Have done a little CFD, seismic data processing software, but currently work in computational chemistry. Also have a MsC in applied mathematics. Have changed subjects so much that I'm no longer sure of what I am, just that I do science! hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

I am a mechanical engineer doing applied math.

Answer (score 0):

I consider myself a computational scientist or applied mathematician, but all of my degrees are in chemical engineering. My PhD is on numerical methods for combustion simulations, which is a field dominated by mechanical engineers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a computational science PhD student, MS. Applied Mathematics & currently conducting research in Mechanical Engineering (computational fluid dynamics).